# Linearly Isometric Banach lattices

Tags: banach-spaces, banach-lattices

Do there exist two Banach lattices which are linearly isometric but not Banach-lattice isometric?  This is so basic that you would expect a textbook or monograph to have answered this, but I have not seen it.

Comment: What about $\ell^2$ and $L^2$?

Comment: Indeed $\ell^2$ unlike $L^2$, has the property $\exists f$, $f\neq 0$, $f\ge 0$ such that every $g$ with $0\le g\le f$ is collinear to $f$. (While $L^2$ satisfies: for every $f\neq 0$ with $f\ge 0$, there exists an infinite countable subset of pairwise orthogonal nonzero elements in $[0,f]$.)

Comment: The above comments correctly answer the question. I would mark the question answered if they had been posted as an answer.  It's a small remark, but I have never seen it brought out in texts which introduce the notion of Banach lattice isometry.